# From Paradox to SQL Server in Borland C++ 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, c++builder, paradox

I'm in the process of converting an old application to work with SQL Server instead of hundreds of Paradox DB files.

I'm using ODBC and most of the stuff is working.

However I do have a problem.

In some forms, is asking for password. I've double checked the `TDatabase` and `TTable` components, added `USER NAME=sa` and `PASSWORD=******` to the Parameters and turned OFF the `LoginPrompt`

What's missing?

Is there any other way to initialize just once all the 5 databases and don't ever ask for password again?!

I've checked other questions here at StackOverflow, but didn't find a suitable one :(

Thank you

Comment: One word of advice: ***never ever*** use the `sa` account for your app - not even in development / testing!

Comment: It's a VM development dedicated machine, I haven't bothered to create a new user :)

Comment: Just don't do it - one day, somehow, in the hectic of your job, you'll forget to change it and leak out your `sa` account's password (and I'm guessing you're using the same `sa` password on multiple systems - right? Thought so...). It **will** happen - trust me. So just don't do it - ***NEVER*** ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Server "Windows Authentication" mode. You can assign the database permissions to a Windows Domain group/groups or individual Windows users. In this case the users will be automatically authenticated to the databases without prompts.

Comment: Just found the culprit :) Yet, I've changed to "Windows Auth Mode" so I don't have the password around the code (thnx marc_s)